Avoid the use of alias in query with nested SELECT clause
I have this table:



id
area
name
value




1
A
abc
1.2


2
B
abc
2.3


3
C
def
3.4



I'm able to calculate the SUM of values for each name:
SELECT 
    name, 
    SUM(value) AS "total" 
FROM table 
GROUP BY name;

and it will output:



name
total




abc
3.5


def
3.4



Now I want to add these values as a calculated column on the table, my expected output is:



id
area
name
value
total




1
A
abc
1.2
3.5


2
B
abc
2.3
3.5


3
C
def
3.4
3.4



My attempt was to add the SELECT clause as column:
SELECT 
    table.*, 
    (SELECT 
        SUM(value) AS "total" 
        FROM table 
        GROUP BY name) 
FROM table

but it fails:

Subquery returns more than 1 row

I understand why: the SELECT will output all the names, not just the one of the current record. So I added a WHERE clause forcing to select only the current name:
SELECT 
    id,
    area,
    name AS current_name,
    value,
    (SELECT 
        SUM(value) 
        FROM table
        WHERE name=current_name
        GROUP BY name) AS "total" 
FROM table

it works!
The downside is the name column is now called current_name.
Is there a way to avoid the use of the alias to keep the actual column name?

You are looking for the window function SUM OVER.
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS total
FROM mytable t

A subquery solution would look like this:
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  (SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.name = t.name) AS total
FROM mytable t


the Answer from @Thorsten Kettner is better if your MySQL version has window function

It seems they work both, even if phpmyadmin compains about the syntax of the window function (but it runs correcly)

By the way, I'm going to use the subquery solution because it supports a filter (i.e. a WHERE clause on the main SELECT without affecting the calculation

Okay. A filter in the window function would look like this: SUM(CASE WHEN x = y THEN value END) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS total. A CASE expression inside the aggregation function is called conditional aggregation.

@ThorstenKettner they meant the other way, the total including all rows but a subset of rows in the main select

try something like this:
SELECT t1.* , t2.total
FROM tabale AS t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
    name, SUM(value) AS "total" 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY name ) AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;

